# Creating .msi installer for only specific Project Output

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, installation, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have a bunch of .net projects and few visual c++ projects, i want to only copy specific output dlls from the build output into the msi project.

1. Two C# library projects
2. One Visual C++ project which uses windows sdk tools and visual c++ runtime libraries.
3. MSI installer which i want to use to install specific output from the above two projects.

Problem Statement: I only want to copy specific files from each of those two projects and bundle everything together along-with some pre-requisites (this i have taken care of creating a powershell script which i run from CMD process inside msi it works fine). Only place i am stuck is copying only specific dll libraries output into the msi project.

[image: Snapshot of my Solution]